# Properties of Cramer's Rule in Matrix Linear Systems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

Given a system of the form 
$$\begin{cases}
ax+by=s \\ cx+dy=t \\
\end{cases}$$
I acknowledge, assuming $a$, $b$, $c$, and, $d$ are real numbers and $ad-bc\ne0$, that we can say 
$$x=\frac{\begin{vmatrix} s & b \\ t & d\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{vmatrix}}, y=\frac{\begin{vmatrix} a & s \\ c & t\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{vmatrix}}
; \text{in other words,} \ x=\frac{Dx}{D} \text{and} \ y=\frac{Dy}{D}$$

My question is: Why is the the $y$ column and the constant column swapped in $Dx$ compared to $Dy$?Whenever I solve systems using Cramer's rule I always have to remind myself to make this swap when finding the minors of an $m \times n$ discriminant, which is frustrating.

Comment: Multiply both sides of the equation giving $x$. Now take $x$ into the determinant, multiplying the first column by it. Multiply the second column by $y$ and add it to the first. See what you get. Similarly for $y$ take it with the second column.

Answer (score 1):

In matrix form,
$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}s\\t\end{bmatrix}$$

When $ax+by = s$ and $cx+dy = t$, the values of $x$ and $y$ can be found by cross-multiplication or by substitution method as follows.

> $$x = \frac{ds-bt}{ad-bc} \ , \ y = \frac{at-cs}{ad-bc}$$

Now, the determinant of the matrices,

$\det\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c&d \end{bmatrix}= ad-bc$

$\det\begin{bmatrix}s & b\\t&d \end{bmatrix}= ds-bt$

and $\det\begin{bmatrix}a & s\\c&t\end{bmatrix}= at-cs$

So,

> $$x = \frac{\begin{vmatrix}s & b\\t&d \end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}a & b\\c&d \end{vmatrix}}\ , \ y = \frac{\begin{vmatrix}a & s\\c&t\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}a & b\\c&d \end{vmatrix}}$$

***Due to this, the columns are swapped.***

To remember, there's a simple rule.

> $\bullet$ If you need to find $x$ replace the column consisting of the co-efficients of $x$ by the column in the RHS.
>
> $\bullet$ If you need to find $y$ replace the column consisting of the co-efficients of $y$ by the column in the RHS.